# How to open fancybox with array of images

Tags: jquery, fancybox

i have an array of images ulrs in JS:

```
photos= ['img1.jpg','img2.jpg',...]
```

I'm using Fancybox 2.

How can I open fancybox with the images of the array?

```
$('#start_slides').fancybox({
    'openEffect'    :   'elastic',
    'closeEffect'   :   'elastic',
    'openSpeed'     :   600, 
    'closeSpeed'    :   200,
    helpers : {
        buttons : {}
    }
});

$.fancybox.open(photos,{});
```

But this is only showing a fancybox with the urls as text.

My final result should be a fancybox with showing the images like a slideshow.

Thanks

Comment: I suggest you post your solution as an answer and remove it from the question. Then in two days tick it, and earn yourself a handsome +2.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I wanted to add it as a new post. But due to I don't had enough points I had to wait 8hrs before I can answer myself.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found a solution:
The photos array must be in the format:

```
photos = [ {href : 'img1.jpg', title : 'Title'}, {href : 'img2.jpg', title : 'Title'} ]
```

Then it is working.

And the initializing is done correctly by:

```
$('#start_slides').fancybox();

$.fancybox.open(photos,{
    'openEffect'    :   'elastic',
    'closeEffect'   :   'elastic',
    'nextEffect'    :   'fade',
    'openSpeed'     :   600, 
    'closeSpeed'    :   200,
    helpers : {
        buttons : {}
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 Perfect. I got an error 'Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /images/800x600/10.jpg' which seemed to come from requireJS. Converting the array passed to fancybox in the format as you mentioned resolved this problem!

Comment: don't you know how would you open these photos at a specific index?