# Open fancybox Gallery after click event on a text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox-2

I found plenty of stuff on StackOverflow and tried different things to achieve what i want, but i'm stuck on this here.

I have a Text in my HTML, if i click this text a fancybox should open with an Image Gallery, the images should come from the `images` Array.

What happens now is that it's opening a broken fancybox, without any styling, opacity, closebutton whatsoever. Here's a example of what it looks like! [image: the broken Fancybox]

My Javascript is the following

```
$(function(){
    $("#turn_all_pictures").click(function(){
        if(images.length == 0){
            loadImages();
        }
        $(this).fancybox();

        $.fancybox.open(
        images,
        {
            'autoScale': true,
            'autoDimensions': true,
            'centerOnScroll': true,
            helpers:{
                overlay:{
                    css:{
                        'background' : 'rgba(58, 42, 45, 0.95)'
                    }
                },
                buttons:{}
            }
        });
    }); 
})
```

An entry in the Array looks like this, which should be right according to this [Stack Overflow Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8828173/how-to-open-fancybox-with-array-of-images)

```
Object { href="<img class="hidden_img fancybox" rel="turn_gallery" src="../../../images/1085/5263-3-medium.jpg"/>"}
```

The needed HTML is this:

```
<p><span class="turn_left" id="turn_all_pictures">Alle Bilder anzeigen</span></p><br>
```

What am i doing wrong, what do i miss so that the fancybox will open correctly formatted and with the image Gallery instead of the Text from the HTML?

**EDIT**

I tried out to append the images in my `loadImages()` function to a div and then ref to this div with my fancybox.

```
$.fancybox.open(
    images,
    {
        // 'autoScale': true,
        // 'autoDimensions': true,
        // 'centerOnScroll': true,
        // helpers:{
        //     overlay:{
        //         css:{
        //             'background' : 'rgba(58, 42, 45, 0.95)'
        //         }
        //     },
        // buttons:{}
        href: '#hidden_pictures'
    }
)
```

That will show all pictures, the whole div, in a fancybox, so i'm guessing that it has something to do with the `images` array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the location of your resources such as your CSS and images for fancybox. You can also inspect your DOM using firebug or some DOM inspection tool to see if your resources are ring found.

I used firebug and looked at the NET tab which showed the http request to the resource. You may see a 404 error if it's not found.

Comment: I already debugged everything with firebug, the images are fine, if i append them with the same function to a div they all show up. Im guessing that it has something to do with my array of images, because the array.push() will add an `Object`.

Comment: Try a test by hard coding the images and see if that's the issue since it could be. Once you figure that's not the issue then you can look at other factors such as your CSS and stuff

Comment: Okay, i hardcoded 2 example images and they will be shown in the facybox, so it must be the generated string. But i can't find a difference between the generated and the hardcoded version, they're the same.

Comment: Okay, the issue was that i overlocked a image that couldn't be found, thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

Check you have passed images array in a format like this:

```
[ 
  {
    href: 'image1.jpg',
    title: 'title 1'
  },
  {
    href: 'image2.jpg',
    title: 'title 2'
  }
]
```

make sure you have included the css properly (check the path)

Also see [this](https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/83)

Comment: I'm adding the images dynamically over the function, looks like this:`images.push({href: '<img class="hidden_img fancybox" rel="turn_gallery" src="../../../images/'+Id1+'/'+Id2+'-'+array[i].id3+'-medium.jpg"/>', title: array[i].Id3});`, a entry of the array is already in the Question.

Comment: { href: "is/path/to/file" },  not the <img/> object itself.

Comment: in your case it will be like { href: "../../../images/'+Id1+'/'+Id2+'-'+array[i].id3+'-medium.jpg"}

Comment: Yeah, i fixed that now, but the images are still not showing up instead of the the text "Alle Bilder anzeigen" from the HTML :/

Comment: hope "Alle Bilder anzeigen" is your title given in <img/> ? you can inspect your code to check the URI given is correct.

Comment: No, "Alle Bilder anzeigen" is just a string in a HTML `<p></p>` tag with an ID. If the ID is clicked the function is called with then will open the fancybox