# Programmatically open fancybox passing an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, fancybox

I have a question regarding jquery fancybox .

My code in load():

```
$(".fanciogallery").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var gid = $(this).data("gid");

    var fancyarray = [];
    //already have an array with the infos
    gallery_array[gid].forEach(function(element){
        var impa = uploadfold + gid + '/immages_' +  element.id_img + '.png';
        //fill an array to pass to fancybox
        fancyarray.push(
            {href : impa, title : 'Title'}                                                           
        );
    });

    $.fancybox.open(
            fancyarray,
            {
                //options
                loop : false
            },
    );
  });
```

I am doing some testing so it's not complete or refined.
I get "The requested content cannot be loaded" but it seems to get the number of elements right.

I get this error even if I hardcode a valid imagepath into

```
href:
```

probably I am filling the array wrong, the documentation it's not clear for me.
Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: try to debug it and checks if your `gallery_array[gid]` is isset and not empty.

Comment: yes yes it's non-empty. Thank you

Comment: It looks like you try to push json in array, maybe this can helps you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12383070/json-array-pushing

Comment: possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8828173/how-to-open-fancybox-with-array-of-images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check samples from documentation - http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#api -

```
$.fancybox.open([
    {
        src  : '1_b.jpg',
        opts : {
            caption : 'First caption',
            thumb   : '1_s.jpg'
        }
    },
    {
        src  : '2_b.jpg',
        opts : {
            caption : 'Second caption',
            thumb   : '2_s.jpg'
        }
    }
], {
    loop : false
});
```

Basically, replace `href` with `src`

Comment: No worries, you were using syntax from v2, but v3 has completely different API.